# Trying to separate the data by user uid firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this in my rules but it's not working, just started using firebase a few weeks ago

```
    match /pets/{owner} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == owner
    }
```

this is the code im using to get the data from the collection:

```
  Stream<List<Pet>> get pets{

    print(userUid);

    return petsCollection.where('owner', isEqualTo: 
       userUid).snapshots().map(_petListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

im using the print to see if i get the uid from the current user for that query, but it comes null. In a diffrent part of the code i already add the uid of the person that creates a document to the collection.

what im trying to say is that i need advice on how to only get the current user data.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code making the request that isn't working the way you expect.  You should also demonstrate that there is actually a user signed in at the time of making that request.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use security rules to filter results

> Once you secure your data and begin to write queries, keep in mind that security rules are not filters. You cannot write a query for all the documents in a collection and expect Cloud Firestore to return only the documents that the current client has permission to access.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0#rules_are_not_filters

Use filter to get current user related documents.

Comment: @LeonardoEmili We don't know if it's actually correct yet. The OP hasn't stated the query that isn't working.  A document get() should work fine (as long as the user is signed in, and they're requesting their own document, which we don't know) but a query get() without a filter will not work.  We also don't even know if they're querying the correct collection.  We need to see the client's query.

Comment: in the query im trying to get the data with the uid but i need an async metod, because im want to add the current users data and make a list with cards